# python sort over list by value Json sctructure

Tags: python, json, sorting

I'm trying to get an output of a json file sorted by the following value "created_at"
there a bit mass regarding all my tries in the code, I wasn't able to sort it.

If there is better solutions to resolve this task you more then welcome to share.

Your help and patience is much appreciated

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
import operator 
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

null = None
true = True
false = False

text = {

    "Recipes":
    [
        {
            "id": 2090210,
            "user_id": 198555,
            "parent_id": null,
            "folder_id": 792876,
            "version_no": 17,
            "last_run_at": "2022-01-13T03:52:31.559455-08:00",
            "created_at": "2022-01-13T00:53:48.433452-08:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-13T03:52:27.798961-08:00",
            "job_succeeded_count": 7,
            "job_failed_count": 0,
            "lifetime_task_count": 209,
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2072031,
            "user_id": 198555,
            "parent_id": null,
            "folder_id": 283206,
            "version_no": 98,
            "last_run_at": "2022-01-04T05:14:41.485273-08:00",
            "created_at": "2022-01-14T05:12:56.677338-08:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-12T10:08:49.199488-08:00",
            "job_succeeded_count": 1,
            "job_failed_count": 0,
            "lifetime_task_count": 227,
            "active": false
        },
    ]
}


#info = json.dump(text, sort_keys=False)
sorted_values = sorted(text.values())
#text.sort(key=lambda s: s['created_at'])
sorted_d = {r: text[r] for r in sorted(text, key=text.get('created_at'), reverse=True)}
#print(sorted_d)
ss = sorted(text.values()) #no recips
#print(ss)
newlist = sorted(ss, key=itemgetter(1))
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to write extra lines just write this one line and it will sort you data

```
sorted_text = { "Recipes" :  sorted(text['Recipes'], key=itemgetter('created_at'))}
print(sorted_text)
```

Comment: sure i will :) just as new user im not able to raise a number until 15 reputation and only in 5 minutes ill be able to accept  i assume its done via teh green V near ur answer

Comment: yeah, the left side of my answer you will find a green button. You can click it to accept answers. thanks